# Permission of / in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

What is the permission of / in Linux machines ?

Is it *root:root with 755 (rwxr-xr-x)* ?

I am not able check the permission with *ls -l*. Please excuse me if this is already answered. I took a quick look but unable to see any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the d option to list permissions for a directory

```
macbook-pro:~ jbrahy$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x@ 42 root  wheel  1496 Jun  2 17:00 / 
macbook-pro:~ jbrahy$
```

Comment: Wow.. Cool bro.. That is indeed the answer... :)

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Jun  6 18:43 /